# A basic doubt on CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is this correct that the following expression $$\int_{-\infty}^{c}F_X(x)dx - \int_{c}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx$$

minimum for $c$ when $F_X(c)=\frac{1}{2}$ ? Here $F_X(x)$ stands for CDF of  random variable $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dc}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{c}F_X(x)\mathrm dx - \int_{c}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))\mathrm dx\right)=F_X(c)-(-1)(1-F_X(c))=1.$$
Suggested remedy: consider instead
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{c}F_X(x)\mathrm dx\  \color{red}{\mathbf +} \int_{c}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))\mathrm dx,
$$
since the derivative with respect to $c$ becomes
$$F_X(c)\  \color{red}{\mathbf +}(-1)(1-F_X(c))=2F_X(c)-1.$$